# Convergence and non-negative supermartingales

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, martingales

Given $ (X_n)_{n\geq0}$ is a non-negative supermartingale and $X_{\infty}$ is an almost sure limit, I want to show that $ \forall n\geq0$ $$\mathbb{E}(X_\infty \mid \mathcal{F}_n) \leq X_n$$

---

**My approach:**

First, for $(X_n)$ a supermartingale I would say we then have $$ \mathbb{E}(X_m\mid\mathcal{F}_n)\leq X_n \quad \forall m\geq n$$ 
Now, my assumption is that $X_m$ does not necessarily converge to $X_\infty$ in $L^1$, so $\mathbb{E}(X_m)$ does not necessarily converge to $\mathbb{E}(X_\infty)$. Hence my idea would be to show that $X_m$ is uniformly integrable, where then we could show, for $X_m \longrightarrow X_\infty$ a.s in $L^1$ then $\mathbb{E}(X_m\mid\mathcal{F}_n) = \mathbb{E}(X_\infty\mid\mathcal{F}_n)$.

However, I think my approach is way off. Could someone please help me out, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By conditional Fatou, $E(\liminf_k X_{n+k}\mid\mathcal F_n)\leq \liminf_k E(X_{n+k}\mid\mathcal F_n)$, hence $$E(X_\infty\mid\mathcal F_n)\leq \liminf_k E(X_{n+k}\mid\mathcal F_n)$$

Since $\forall k, E(X_{n+k}\mid\mathcal F_n)\leq X_n$, we have $\liminf_k E(X_{n+k}\mid\mathcal F_n)\leq X_n$ and the result follows.

Comment: why do we have $n+k$?

Comment: @math189925 because I decided so. $n$ is fixed throughout the proof.

Comment: could you also do $n+1$?

Comment: @math189925 no, you need an index that goes to $\infty$. $X_{n+k}$ converges almost surely to $X_\infty$ as $k$ goes to $\infty$.

Comment: ah yes of course, that makes perfect sense! Thank you very much.